# How to call constructor of component in Yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I created a component `class Comp extends CApplicationComponent`
and define it in `main.php`

Presently I am passing value to its `constructor` as
`$comp = new Comp($value);`.

Is it possible to call its constructor using `Yii::app()->comp`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no convenient way of doing this in Yii 1.1 - every component should be instance of `IApplicationComponent` with configuration in public properties and actual initialization in `init()`. That is why there is so many Yii extensions which are simple wrappers for generic PHP libraries - you need to create such wrapper for each class which does not follow Yii convention for defining components.

Answer (score -1):

Once you autoload it in config/main.php you can use the component anywhere in the application (controller or module)

Comment: I know this, all I want is to call the component of constructor using Yii::app()->comp

Answer (score -1):

In your config.main add in the array 'components' the class that you want somethign like this:

```
 'clientScript' => [
            'class' => "ext.ClientScript.ClientScriptManager"
        ],
```

Where '**ext**' is "protected/extension' and the '**ClientScript**' is the name of the folder and  the '**ClientScriptManager**' is name of the class.